# Short Ternary operator when finding non-existing keys

Tags: php

Is it legal to do something like this (without warnings):

```
$code = [
    0=>'code0',
    1=>'code1'
];

$key = 3;
echo $code[$key] ?: 'unknown';
```

I.e. using `?:` instead to do:

```
echo isset($code[$key]) ? $code[$key] : 'unknown';
```

PHP > 5.3

Comment: No, since you would try to access an undefined index. But in PHP 7 you will be able to do: `echo $code[$key] ?? "unkown";`

Comment: you can make an answer for that

Comment: You should use isset method. It is always preferable as it will suit on any system. Otherwise your code became system dependent.

Comment: it's very ugly using that isset you have to repeat two times